# Why isn't formyl chloride stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds, halides, stability

I am currently studying methods of synthesising ketones and aldehydes and one of the methods is Friedel-Crafts acylation. However, my teacher told our class that we can't use this to make benzaldehyde as formyl chloride, HCOCl, is unstable. Why is HCOCl unstable?

Comment: For formylation you'd need HCOCl - it's indeed unstable, but it can be done nontheless.

Comment: Oh,OK. Thank you. But why is it unstable though?

Comment: The problem of the stability is not yet perfectly understood in chemistry ?. Why is SO not really stable at  room temperature ? Why is NO so stable at room temperature ?  Why does HNO not exist long enough to be stored in a bottle ?